# MAUI GoToAsync() with navigationargs doesn't work

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I made a MAUI Shell app with 3 navigables content pages with a TabBar.

In the `MainPage`, the user enter many inputs, and then click on a button.
When the user click, I want to navigate to `ListPage` witch contain a **ListView** and display the content of a **List** passed as argument.

> AppShell.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="CALCULATEUR_ODT.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CALCULATEUR_ODT"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
    Title="AppShell">

    <TabBar x:Name="TAB01">
        <Tab x:Name="ORDER" Title="ORDRE" Route="P_Order" Icon="point">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab x:Name="FEU" Title="FEU" Route="P_Fire" Icon="feu">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:FirePage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab x:Name="LISTE" Title="LISTE" Route="P_List" Icon="liste">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ListPage}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>
```

> MainPage.xaml ButtonClick procedure

**LIST_TIR** is a **List** contained in the **NewOrder** object.

```
private async void CALC()
{
    if (LOAD_VAR(NewOrder))
    {
        var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "firelist", NewOrder.LIST_TIR }
        };
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//P_List", navigationParameter);
    }
}
```

> ListPage.xaml

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(FireList), "firelist")]
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    private List<TIR> FireList = new List<TIR>();

    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;

        LST01_LP_TIR.ItemsSource = FireList;
    }
}
```

I don't get any error while running, but the ListView **LST01_LP_TIR** is not filled and I'm sure that **NewOrder.LIST_TIR** is not empty.

Comment: you should never assume that properties are populated at the time the constructor executes

Comment: @Jason You mean I need to put  LST01_LP_TIR.ItemsSource = FireList; in another method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the **UI updates** as the data changes, initialise FireList inside the property's setter rather than in the property declaration. This is how you can change it:

```
private List<TIR> _fireList = new List<TIR>();
public List<TIR> FireList
{
    get => _fireList;
    set
    {
        _fireList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FireList)); // Notify the UI to update.
        LST01_LP_TIR.ItemsSource = _fireList; 
    }
}
```

Your ContentPage must implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface in order to support the **OnPropertyChanged** method for the aforementioned code to function. You will need to add the following if ListPage does not currently implement it:

```
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Implement the interface here
}
```

Also note that The **QueryProperty** system sets properties after the constructor has run. This means your initial binding in the constructor to LST01_LP_TIR.ItemsSource might not work as expected because FireList is still empty at that point.

Make that the **ItemSource** is set in the setter for the property, as demonstrated above, or in a method that is called after the property is set (e.g., overriding **OnAppearing**).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it's works.

Here the final code :

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(FireList), "firelist")]
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<TIR> _fireList = new List<TIR>();
    public List<TIR> FireList
    {
        get => _fireList;
        set
        {
            _fireList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FireList));
        }
    }

    public ListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        LST01_LP_TIR.ItemsSource = _fireList;
    }
}
```